# C# linq to sql default connection string

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-3.0, app-config

In an existing C# 2010 application, I want to add linq to sql tatements to connect to a sql server 2008 database. When I setup this linq to sql database, I want to be able to setup the connections to the database using the app.config file.

I have read that when you setup the database connection this way, the default database is used. Basically this is ok when you database on the same database. However, when  you move from a unit testing database to a user acceptance and/or a production database there is a problem since the database connection is hard coded in the aqpplication.

Thus can you tell me and/or show me with code how to prevent this problem from occuring?

Comment: You have a web.config per environment and use build > configuration management to target which web.config to use (e.g., debug, alpha, beta). It's the same for unit tests except you use an app.config file. Unit testing on alpha, beta, and live would be handled by continuous integration.

Comment: When you create the connection in Visual Studio for the Linq To SQL data context it _should_ create a connection string in the config file.  That would be what you configure.  It has a default hard-coded one in the Settings file as well, but the config should override that.  Another option is to add a custom Connection String value to the config file and initialize the data context with that specific one.

Comment: Nit-picky side note: If the test involves a database, it's not a unit test.  It's an integration test :)

Comment: What's a "unit testing database"?

Comment: how can you make the config file override the settings file?

Answer (score 1):

You must create partial class like [This](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/using-the-web-config-connection-string-with-linq-to-sql/)